# Angularjs calling a service function from the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller, angular-ui-router, angularjs-scope

I've been searching the web but I can't find why I get this error

> "checkDishService.checkDish is not a function"

in the console when calling a service function from my controller.

Please, help!

Here is the service:

```
  (function () {
        'use strict';

        angular.module('public')
        .service('checkDishService', checkDishService);

        checkDishService.$inject = ['$http','$q', '$timeout']
        function checkDishService($http,$q, $timeout) {
            var service = this;
            var items = [];

            service.checkDish = function (shortName) {

                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http.get('https://www.example.com/menu_items/'+shortName+'.json').success(function(data) {
                    service.items = data;
                    // Wait 2 seconds before returning
                    $timeout(function () {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                        }, 400);
                })
                .error(function() {
                    deferred.reject("No such dish exists");
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            };
        }



    })();
```

Here's the controller:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('restaurant', ['public'])
    .controller('RegistrationController', RegistrationController);

    RegistrationController.$inject = ['checkDishService','$scope','$stateParams'];

    function RegistrationController($stateParams,  checkDishService, $scope) {
        var reg = this;     
        reg.checkDish = function(shortName){
            if(shortName)
            {

                checkDishService.checkDish(shortName).then(function(res){
                    //the line before is the line throwing the error
                });

            }


        }
    }
})();
```

And here's the form from where I call the controller:

```
<div ng-controller="RegistrationController as reg">
        <form name='regForm' novalidate>

            <input type="text" name="dish" placeholder="Favorite dish"
                ng-model="reg.user.dish" ng-blur="reg.checkDish(reg.user.dish)"
                required
                minlength="1"
                maxlength="4">
            {{ reg.user.dish }}
            <br>
            <span ng-show="regForm.dish.$invalid.checkDish">No such dish exists.</span>

            <button
                ng-disabled="regForm.$invalid"
                ng-click="reg.submit()">Submit</button>


        </form>
</div>
```

The checkdish function is trying to check is the dish exists before the user clicks the submit button.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass parameters in the correct order of your injection. Change the order like this

```
RegistrationController.$inject = ['checkDishService','$scope','$stateParams'];

function RegistrationController(checkDishService, $scope, $stateParams) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameters order should be always same like order of injection.

```
RegistrationController.$inject = ['checkDishService','$scope','$stateParams'];

function RegistrationController(checkDishService, $scope, $stateParams )
```

Anyways I hope you got your answer.